# Is this clear and efficient LINQ to join several tables/models and then group the results?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1

Is there another way to group the results of several joined models? Selecting each model into an anonymous type and then grouping works, but I don't know that it's the right way to do it.

All conditionals are in the three `IQueryables` I setup outside this query: `attrDatas, dataIds, and filterIds`.

```
var query = (
    from a in attrDatas
    join d in dataIds
        on a.Id equals d.Id
    join f in filterIds
        on new { a.Id, a.AltId } equals new { f.Id, f.AltId }
    select new
    {
        ad = a,
        di = d,
        //fi = f,
    }
    into grouped
    group grouped by grouped.ad.AltId into g
    select new VwModel
    {
        AltId = g.Key,
        MaxReturn = g.Max(z => z.ad.Return),
        PriceUsd = g.Max(z => z.ad.Price),
        ApproxVal = g.Sum(z => (z.ad.Price*z.ad.Shares)),
        HoldDate = g.Max(z => z.di.HoldDate),
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any other way. Below the hood `group by` is equivalent to the [`GroupBy()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb154757.aspx) extension method. Of each overload, the first input parameter is an `IQueryable<TSource>`, which is *the only parameter that carries data*. (The other parameters are `Expression`s that determine the grouping and the output). So this input list should contain everything you want to show in the result set after grouping.

Therefore you have to build an anonymous type (≠ generic, by the way). Using `group a by a.AltId`, for example, pushes `d` and `f` out of scope.

Comment: Thanks for confirming and clarifying my understanding of the `group by` method. The trickiest part is second paragraph - understanding that `d` and `f` get kicked out of scope.